# Displaying Text Window in Leaflet (infowindow)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to display some information in map (text) as a standalone window (draggable and connected via line with some marker).

Basically I'm looking for some way how to have something like [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) from google maps.

I started with *hacking* popups, but there is a problem with just one opened popup (can be solved by overriding openPopUp method in map) and it seems its getting worse (partially not working state updates and so on)

thanks for any advice!

links:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: Please post a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with
JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: «but there is a problem with just one opened popup» - and what's that problem, exactly?